Angular select (dropdown) not binding correctly to data
I'm using Angular 17 CSR and I'm having trouble to correctly display a simple select with the name of the countries and the ids as values
This is the data that I'm recieving, which is fine, a two items array

Here is the template
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="suggestParkingForm">
        <h4>Select a country:</h4>
        <select class="form-control" name="countrySelect">
            <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country.CountryId">{{ country.Name }}</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

Here is my component logic
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CountryDTO } from '../../dtos/CountryDTO';
import { CountryCityService } from '../../services/country-city.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countries-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './countries-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './countries-list.component.scss'
})
export class CountriesListComponent implements OnInit {

  countries!: CountryDTO[];
  suggestParkingForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private countryService: CountryCityService) {
    this.suggestParkingForm = new FormGroup({
      country: new FormControl(null)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.countryService.getAllCountries().subscribe(countries => {
      this.countries = countries;
      console.log(this.countries);
    });
  }

}

And here is the model used to map and display the select options
export class CountryDTO {
    CountryId: number;
    Name: string;

    constructor(countryId: number, name: string) {
        this.CountryId = countryId;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

I have changed [value] to [ngValue] with the same result
The select actually has two items but the text is empty


Typo error. Your API response returns the fields in the camel case, but you are specifying the field name in the Pascal case. country.CountryId, country.Name

See that Angular is "case sensitive"
See also that you need indicate to the select is a FormControl (use formControlName, so should be
<form [formGroup]="suggestParkingForm">
    <h4>Select a country:</h4>
    <select formControlName="country" 
            name="countrySelect" class="form-control" >
        <!--you can indicate that the user should select
            a country adding one option with hidden disabled-->
        <option [value]="null" disabled hidden >Select one country</option>
        <option *ngFor="let country of countries" 
               [value]="country.countryId">{{ country.name }}</option>
    </select>
</form>

NOTE 1: It's very common that, althought in your API you define the property in PascalCase the properties (the first characte in upperCase), you get to your font'-end as CamelCase (the first character in lowerCase)
NOTE 2: You use [ngValue] when each "option" is an object (you want the formControl get the value of the whole object), but if you only need a simple data (a string, a number) you can use simply [value]
NOTE 3: if you want initialize your select with one value you can give value when you create the formGroup
this.suggestParkingForm = new FormGroup({
  country: new FormControl(1)
});

or using setValue
this.suggestParkingForm.get('country')?.setValue(1)


Two things solved this problem

matching the case of the json properties in the model

export class CountryDTO {
    countryId: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(countryId: number, name: string) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}


Changing [ngValue] to [value]

